# MySQL join comes up with null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am taking data from 3 tables and joining them  (i will shorten information given to the relevant parts)

table entry

```
date / id / ...
5/1/2017  /  1
5/2/2017  /  2
5/3/2017  /  3
.
.
.
6/1/2017  /  42
```

table engdailydata

```
entry_id / enginehrs / ...
1  / 654186
2  / 655000
3  / 660000
.
.
.
42  / 800000
```

table 24hrlog

```
date / air1 / ..
6/1/2017  /  4200
```

I am trying to get a list out of this that has all dates that are in either entry or 24hrlog table

The SQL works to show all the values except the date (if date is missing in one of them I get null value)

```
SELECT 
    `entry`.`date` AS `date1`,
    `24hrlog`.`date` AS `date2`,
   engdailydata`.`enginehrs1` AS `enginehrs1`,
    `24hrlog`.`air1` AS `air1`
     FROM
    (`engdailydata`
    LEFT JOIN (`24hrlog`
    JOIN `entry` ON ((`entry`.`date` = `24hrlog`.`date`))) ON 
                    ((`entry`.`entry_id` = `engdailydata`.`entry_id`)))
```

For Example running this I am returned 40 rows.

```
date1 / date2 / enginehrs1 / air1
NULL  / NULL  /  654186    / NULL
NULL  / NULL  /  655000    / NULL
NULL  / NULL  /  660000    / NULL
.
.
.
6/1/2017  /  6/1/2017  / 800000  / 4200
```

What I am trying to get

```
date1 / date2 / enginehrs1 / air1
5/1/2017  / NULL  /  654186    / NULL
5/2/2017  / NULL  /  655000    / NULL
5/3/2017  / NULL  /  660000    / NULL
.
.
.
6/1/2017  /  6/1/2017  / 800000  / 4200
```

Comment: edited main post for further clarification

Comment: Your query has a very strange join syntax which I think is invalid and should be rejected by the DBMS. As to your tables: An `entry` is identified by its ID. Every `entry` has a date. For every `entry.id` we can find zero, one or many records in `engdailydata`. There is also a table `24hrlog` containing dates. Now you want to show all `entry` data with all their `engdailydata` data along with the `24hrlog` data if the `engdailydata.date` exists in `24hrlog` or without if it doesn't. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN`'s purpose is to preserve rows in the resultset taken from the right side of the join that don't match that `JOIN`'s `ON` condition.  The columns from the left side of the `JOIN` in that case come out null.

Try changing your `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` (an abbreviation for `INNER JOIN`). That will suppress the rows with nulls from the resultset.

Comment: that doesn't work for what I want to do since inner join removes the rows in one table that doesn't exist in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this solution, but I expect there is a better one..

Create view

```
VIEW `runhrs1` AS
    SELECT 
        `entry`.`date` AS `date1`,
        `engdailydata`.`enginehrs1` AS `enginehrs1`
    FROM
        (`engdailydata`
        JOIN `entry` ON ((`entry`.`entry_id` = `engdailydata`.`entry_id`)))
```

Then create second view

```
VIEW `runhrs` AS
    SELECT 
        `24hrlog`.`air1` AS `air1`,
        `runhrs1`.`date1` AS `date`,
        `runhrs1`.`enginehrs1` AS `enginehrs1`,

    FROM
        (`runhrs1`
        LEFT JOIN `24hrlog` ON ((`runhrs1`.`date1` = `24hrlog`.`date`)))
UNION

SELECT 
        `24hrlog`.`air1` AS `air1`,
        `runhrs1`.`date1` AS `date`,
        `runhrs1`.`enginehrs1` AS `enginehrs1`,

    FROM
        (`runhrs1`
        Right JOIN `24hrlog` ON ((`runhrs1`.`date1` = `24hrlog`.`date`)))
```

Comment: Ah, so you are looking for a full outer join (which MySQL doesn't support). You want all entry/engdailydata even when their date doesn't exist in 24hrlog. And you also want a result row per 24hrlog where the date has no match in entry/engdailydata. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

You want a full outer join, but MySQL doesn't support this unfortunately. One way to go about this is to create a set with all dates on-the-fly and then outer join the tables:

```
select
  all_dates.date,
  log.air1,
  edd.enginehrs
from
(
  select date from entry
  union
  select date from 24hrlog
) all_dates
left join 24hrlog log on log.date = all_dates.date
left join entry e on e.date = all_dates.date
left join engdailydata edd on edd.entry_id = e.entry_id;
```